# Comparison between the two printf statements

Tags: c, string, compiler-construction, printf

please take a look at the two following c statements

```
printf("a very long string");
printf("%s","a very long string");
```

they produce the **same** result,but there is definitely some difference **under the hood**,so what is the difference and which one is **better**? Please share your ideas!

Comment: 'under the hood', you mean? I don't think too many people in the hood will be worried about what printf's doing internally.

Comment: very implementation specific this question is

Comment: Better would probably be to use `puts("a very long string")`.

Comment: @Sander: but `puts` adds a newline to the end of the string...  Maybe `fputs`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know what the string contents are, you should use the first form because it is more compact. If the string you want to print can come from the user or from any other source such that you do not know what the string contents are, you *must* use the second form; otherwise, your code will be wide open to [format string injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Format_String).

Comment: format-string-injection-attacks is new to me,anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

The first `printf` works like this

```
'a' is not a special character: print it
' ' is not a special character: print it
'v' is not a special character: print it
...
'g' is not a special character: print it
```

The second `printf` works like this

```
'%' is a special character:
    's' print the contents of the string pointed to by the 2nd parameter
```

Comment: This explanation also highlight the security risk of format-injection as explained by @Aasmund Eldhuset in a separate answer.

I.e. if you don't know what exact content is in the 'very long string' then you should _never_ do the first option, instead use the second %s option or a puts call.

Comment: I agree that this answers the question, but i would like to emphasize that if you're worried about performance that much, then you should probably not be using puts, etc. instead of printf

Answer (score 1):

The first one passes one parameter and the second passes 2, so the call is slightly faster in the first one.

But in the first one, printf() has to scan the long string for format specifications and in the second one, the format string is very short, so the actual processing is probably faster in the second one.

More important (to me anyway), is that "a very long string" is not likely to be a a constant string as it is in this example. If you're printf'ing a long string, you're probably using a pointer to to something that the program generated.  In that case, it's a MUCH better idea to use the second form because otherwise somewhere, somehow, sometime, the long string will contain a format printf format specification and that will cause printf to go looking for another argument and your program will crash.   This exact problem just happened to me about a week ago in code that we have been using for nearly 20 years.

The bottom line is that your printf format specification should always be a constant string.  If you need to output a variable, use `printf("%s",var)` or better yet, `fputs(var, stdout)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first is no less efficient than the second. Since there are no format sequences and no corresponding arguments, no work must be done by the printf() function. In the second case, if the compiler isn't smart enough to catch this, you will be calling for unnecessary work (note: miniscule compared to actually sending (and reading!) the output at the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

printf was designed for printing with **formatting**. It is more useful to provide formatting arguments for the sake of debugging although they aren't required.

%s takes a value of a const char* whereas leaving no argument just prints the literal expression.

You could still cast a different pointer to the const char* explicitly and change its contents without changing the output expression.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should define "better" better since it is not smart enough by itself. Better in what way? performance, maintenance, readibility, extensibilty ...

With the one line of code presented I would choose option 1 for almost all versions of 'better'

- It's more readible
- It does what it should do and nothing more (KISS principle)
- It's faster (no pointless moving memory around to stuff one string into another). But unless you are doing this printf a hell of a lot of times in a loop this is not that a big plus.

Comment: your advice is good,the reason why i did not define "better" is that i dont want to limit the ways it can be in, so people can share whatever he comes out.